# Getting to a specific page on website using specific code instead of navigation bar

Tags: pages, search

Is there a way get to a specific page on a WordPress website by entering in a code instead of going through the navig

Comment: I'd recommend you do some research first. WordPress is all over the internet with tutorials, descriptions and documentation. The way you ask unfortunately suggests, that you have not done any research at all. Sorry to be straight forward, but that is how it appears to me. Others may think differently.

Comment: In what context? Do you mean code that you'd add to a template or plugin? Or a code that the user would enter? If it's the latter, where would they be entering it? You'll need to be considerably more specific about what you want to achieve. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so _all_ the information needs to be in the question.